# Invalid Redis password while deploying Rails5 beta3 app with ActionCable on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

First of all, my application just works fine in development.
I've been following tutorials to deploy an Action Cable app on Heroku, but I hit this problem:

My app's config is that way :

config/cable.yml:

```
development: &development
  :url: redis://localhost:6379
  :host: localhost
  :port: 6379
  :timeout: 1
  :inline: true
test: *development
production: &production
  :url: redis://redistogo:MYREDISTOGOPASSWORD@lab.redistogo.com:10108/
  :host: tarpon.redistogo.com
  :port: 10108
  :password: MYREDISTOGOPASSWORD
  :inline: true
  :timeout: 1
```

initilizer/redis.rb

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || 'redis://localhost:6379/' )
REDIS = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
```

this line in config/routes.rb

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

In the app in production, I've no JS console errors or warnings, but in the logs, I can see why the ActionCable magic isn't working, and it seems that my redistogo password is wrong when the websocket try to access it ?
I can `heroku run console` and then try `REDIS.set()/get()` and it's working well.

In the logs, I have this error :

```
2016-04-23T23:26:36.308976+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 1078) booted, phase: 0
2016-04-23T23:26:36.316316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cable" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=7752b409-3d26-4a82-9e39-73c34eb6819c fwd="90.109.65.65" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=170ms status=101 bytes=129
2016-04-23T23:26:37.090881+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" for 90.109.65.65 at 2016-04-23 23:26:37 +0000
2016-04-23T23:26:37.139914+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for 90.109.65.65 at 2016-04-23 23:26:37 +0000
2016-04-23T23:26:37.139965+00:00 app[web.1]: Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240234+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:121:in `call': ERR invalid password (Redis::CommandError)
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240241+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102:in `block in connect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240243+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240244+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `with_socket_timeout'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:133:in `call_loop'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240246+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:43:in `subscription'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240247+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:12:in `subscribe'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240248+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:2760:in `_subscription'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240248+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:2138:in `block in subscribe'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240251+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:2137:in `subscribe'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:70:in `block in listen'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:64:in `block in with_reconnect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240255+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240256+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240256+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240257+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:63:in `with_reconnect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240259+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:67:in `listen'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240259+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis.rb:70:in `without_reconnect'
2016-04-23T23:26:37.240261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:141:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just lost so much time on this one. The problem was I just messed up with another redistogo subdomain while following too closely examples...

config/cable.yml:

```
production: &production
  :url: redis://redistogo:MYREDISTOGOPASSWORD@lab.redistogo.com:10108/
  -------
  :host: tarpon.redistogo.com
  +++++++
  :host: lab.redistogo.com
```